# To Avoid French Characters in Request XML

Tags: xslt

There is a requirement where we are asked to identify French Characters in the request xml and either replace it with English character or reject the request. Is there any easy way to implement this in DataPower/xslt?

One option I can think of is, to do match operation on request xml string to scan any French character, but it seems a cumbersome approach to me. Looking for some better way to do this.

Comment: What are French characters, in your opinion?

Comment: if any French characters in request xml file then only replace it with English characters through cutom xslt code

Comment: Would you mind answering my question?

Comment: French Character's ùûüÿ€àâæçéèêëïîôœ

Answer (score 1):

If each "French character" needs to be replaced with a **single** "English character", you can do so very easily by using the translate() function.

If there are characters that need to be replaced by more than one character, for example `"œ"` to `"oe"`, then you can use the replace() function - if you are using XSLT 2.0. Otherwise you will need a named recursive template to perform this operation.

I am not sure what "reject the request" means in terms of XSLT.

--
P.S. IMHO, this kind of processing shouldn't be required in 2014.